# Webpack code splitting without requiring all scripts in html

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

The following configuration will create client.js and vendors.js.

**example**

Entry

```
entry: {
  'client': './client.js',
  'vendors' ['jquery' , 'react']
}
```

Plugin

```
     new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'client',
        minChunks: Infinity
     }),
     new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendors',
        chunks: ['client'],
        minChunks: Infinity
     })
```

To make it work, I need to add the client.js and vendor.js files in the HTML, otherwise i will get the error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined.*

How can I include only the client.js file in the index.html and make it require the vendors.js file automatically?

I would like to obtain the same behaviour that I get when I split the code with require.ensure.

Comment: For code splitting automatically & then auto loading, you might want to look at the require.ensure() method.  If you do this, you just have the one entry point, and leave the rest to webpack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already knew that. But is it possible to do the explicit splitting from the entry and the auto loading script?

Comment: Not that I know off, sorry.  Someone might have created a plugin who knows??.  The problem is if your not using require.ensure(), there is no way a script could auto-load a previous one without making the current one load the previous script in synchronous (blocking mode), and that's not really ideal.